# How to send POST data to a new page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, file, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send POST data (files) to a new webpage or reload the page and keep the POST data using Javascript.

I can't use a form because I want to allow the user to be able to select multiple files one by one an that requires me to use preventDefault() and send the data using Javascript.

My code:

```js
var storedFiles = [];

const form = document.querySelector('#myform');

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initFileStorage, false);

function initFileStorage() {

  // add the change listener on file input
  document.getElementById("uploadFile")
    .addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, false);

}

function handleFileSelect(e) {

  // check if any files has been selected. If not, exit
  if (!e.target.files) return;

  var files = e.target.files;
  var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);

  // push new selected files into the common file storage
  filesArr.forEach((f) => storedFiles.push(f));

}

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {

  //disable default form action
  event.preventDefault();

  var uploadName = document.getElementById("uploadnaam").value;

  //create new formdata
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("theFiles", storedFiles);
  formData.append("uploadName", uploadName);
  formData.append("th", 'th');

  //configure new XMLHttpRequest
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "index.php", true);

  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

  //send data
  xhr.send(formData);

  xhr.onload = () => {

    JSON.stringify(storedFiles);

    console.log(storedFiles);

  };

});
```

```html
<form title='upload files' id='myform'>

  <h3>Upload File</h3>

  <input title='input your files here' type="file" id='uploadFile' name='files[]' multiple />

  <br>

  <input type="text" id="uploadnaam" placeholder="naam upload (verplicht)" autocomplete="off">

  <br>

  <button type='submit' id='mySubmitButton' name="save">UPLOAD</button>

</form>
```

So right now when you submit the files the page will not reload (my goal is to run a file called filesLogic.php and now I do that by including it in the header) the page that I want because I want filesLogic to run with the POST data. And if I remove the event.preventDefault() then the page will reload but the POST data will be lost. Does anyone know how I can run filesLogic.php/refresh the page with and keep the post data.

Comment: what are you getting in the network tab? can you share it?

Comment: Are you committed to using the `onchange` event to fire the upload script or can you tolerate the user clicking a button once he/she has selected all the files they want and completed the `text` field?

Comment: @AdisonMasih When I submit the form this row is added to the network tab: 'index.php 200 xhr (index):152 5.3 kB 39 ms'

Comment: Why not include `filesLogic` in the same page? If there's POST data do something with it, else display the form.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Both ways are fine to me. This is just how I tried it, if you know a different way to make it work I'd be glad to use that.

Comment: @Michel I did include it in the same page, I just didn't add it in the snippit. However it only runs when the page is loaded for the first time, and then there is no POST data yet, so now I want to be able to run the code form that file with the PSOT data.

Comment: Can you tell us what do you see inside the request? the headers, the body, the parameters etc?

Comment: One simple method (perhaps) might be to change the button type from a submit (which is the default for a button) to a regular `button` - ie: `<button type='button' name='upload'>Upload</button>`?

Comment: @AdisonMasih here is some info from the headers: Request URL: http://localhost/uploadsysteem/index.php
Request Method: POST

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Content-Type: multipart/form-data

Origin: http://localhost
Referer: http://localhost/uploadsysteem/

------WebKitFormBoundaryWe4WncGdbIMUEjwc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="theFiles"

------WebKitFormBoundaryWe4WncGdbIMUEjwc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadName"


------WebKitFormBoundaryWe4WncGdbIMUEjwc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="th"

th
------WebKitFormBoundaryWe4WncGdbIMUEjwc--

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do with the POST data on the front end? Do you want to keep the form? Or only the file name and the uploadname?

Comment: @Michel I am trying to make a file-uploader. So in filesLogic.php I will send the information to my database (where I store the files). So I need the files and the uploadname and not only the filename.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I now made the button a normal button and it works, but evrything still works the same, the page still doesn't refresh and the POST data is still only stored in the current webpage.

Comment: I don't get the problem. If you store it in the database, is there any need to have the uploadname and filename at the frond end? Send it to the server, insert in database and refresh the page with empty form.

Comment: @Michel It is necessary to send the information to the database through filesLogic.php, and it does need an uploadname. That's the way the site is build, the site is a lot bigger than this snippit, but I just need to know how to do this. I only need to know how to run the php file with the POST information from javascript.

Comment: Is it one `uploadname` per file selected? Or one `uploadname` for multiple files??